# Why does Python's threading.Condition use an RLock by default?

Tags: python, multithreading

`threading.Condition` takes a lock as an argument, but if none is specified, it uses a `threading.RLock` by default. I found this out when I called `acquire` on a condition variable in one thread, and then handed it over to another thread to `wait` on it. This fails with an `RLock`, so the solution is to use a normal lock. What's the rationale behind using `RLock` by default?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An `RLock` is used by default to prevent the very thing you're trying to do.  In order to guarantee that the predicate is protected, locks are acquired and conditions are waited on in the *same thread*.  Using an `RLock` guarantees this.

When using a `Lock` with a condition, there's no implicit guarantee that the predicate is protected since the locking thread can be mucking with it in parallel.

Comment: It also makes general usage less likely to deadlock. If one method acquires the lock to ensure sync, calls another method (which also acquires it for whatever reason), then `RLock` will work just fine (the underlying lock is acquired only once, with a total acquisition count of 2), while `Lock` would block on the second acquire. Fixing it would require the second method to have an unlocked version (for method 1 to call) with a wrapper that locked first, which complicates the code and makes it easier to accidentally misuse. Basically, we use `RLock` because it's less likely to misbehave.

Comment: Of course, the downside to this choice is that on CPython 2, `RLock` is a Python level wrapper around the C implemented `Lock`, so the overhead of using it is much higher (a bunch of Python code executed every time instead of just a direct call to C). Which is another argument for using Python 3.x; it's C implemented there (with new features like interrupting lock acquisition w/signals, C level support for timed acquires, etc.); overhead from lock contention in many cases drops from almost equal to actual work performed in Py2 to single digit percent indistinguishable from noise in Py3.2+.